# Is there a way to create two rows of strings from an R function?

Tags: r

So I want to create a column of data that will be formatted exactly like this:

```
Hello, my name is: 
BLuta
```

And from a grand scheme of things, I want the table to look like this...

[image]

However, if I were to run the code...

```
df$labels <- paste("Hello, my name is:", "BLuta", sep = " ")
```

It would create something like this, which is what I am not looking for:

```
Hello, my name is: BLuta
```

Is that possible to make this happen? Any assistance is truly appreciated.

Comment: You may need `cat` with `sep="\n" `?

Comment: Thanks. By using one set of texts at a time, it works, but I realized that this won't work if I'm trying to do this in a table format. Please see changes from the above to see what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

We may use `cat`

```
cat("hello, my name is:\nBLuta", "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. By using one set of texts at a time, it works, but I realized that this won't work if I'm trying to do this in a table format. Please see changes from the above to see what I'm looking for.